# Error on access db variable from a mongoldb mapReduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, runtime-error

Hi' I'm writing an application that use a MongoDB database.
I've a user collection, that store all the user data.
A document has the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542e67e07f724fc2af28ba75"),
    "id" : "",
    "email" : "luigi@gmail.com",
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Liners - Baking Cups",
            "weight" : 2,
            "lastInsert" : 1412327492874
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - Jumbo",
            "weight" : 4,
            "lastInsert" : 1412597883569
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Paper Goods:Lialberto- Baking Cups",
            "weight" : 1,
            "lastInsert" : 1412327548205
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Fish:Swordfish Loin Portions",
            "weight" : 3,
            "lastInsert" : 1412597939124
        },
        {
            "tag" : "Vegetable:Carrots - alberto@gmail.com",
            "weight" : 2,
            "lastInsert" : 1412597939124
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I've created a recommendation.tagsMatch collection that store the similarity between two tags.

A document of the collection has the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : "Fish:Swordfish Loin Portions-Paper Goods:Lialberto- Baking Cups",
    "value" : {
        "tag1" : "Fish:Swordfish Loin Portions",
        "tag2" : "Paper Goods:Lialberto- Baking Cups",
        "sum1" : 3,
        "sum2" : 1,
        "sumQ1" : 9,
        "sumQ2" : 1,
        "sumProd" : 3,
        "count" : 2
    }
}
```

Now I'm writing a mapReduce from a document of `recommendation.users` to a `recommendation.tagsMatch` document.

If it's the first time that the document is map the `value.count` field had to be 0, otherwise `value.count` had to be the old value in the corresponding `recommendation.tagsMatch` document.

I've implementing my mapReduce function as following:

```
var f1 = function() {
            var rows = this.tags;    
            if (rows != undefined) {
                rows = rows.sort(function(a, b){return a.tag > b.tag}) 
                rows.forEach( function(rowThis) {
                    if (rows != undefined) {
                        /** prendo solo i maggiori di quello che sto confrontando */
                        var toCompare = rows.filter(function(e){return rowThis.tag  < e.tag;})
                        toCompare.forEach( function(rowThat) {
                        var key = rowThis.tag + "-" + rowThat.tag;
                var documentValue = db.recommendation.tagsMatch.find({_id: key}).one()
                    var countValue = 0
                if(documentValue.value.count != undefined) 
                        countValue = documentValue.value.count                          
                            var value = {
                                tag1: rowThis.tag,
                                tag2: rowThat.tag,
                                sum1: rowThis.weight,
                                sum2: rowThat.weight,
                                sumQ1: Math.pow(rowThis.weight, 2),
                                sumQ2: Math.pow(rowThat.weight, 2),
                                sumProd: rowThis.weight * rowThat.weight,
                                count: countValue
                            }
                            emit(key, value);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };



var r1 = function(key, values) {
            var reducedObject = {
                tag1: "",
                tag2: "",
                sum1: 0,
                sum2: 0,
                sumQ1: 0,
                sumQ2: 0,
                sumProd: 0,
                count: 0
            }
            values.forEach( function(value) {
                reducedObject.tag1 = value.tag1;
                reducedObject.tag2 = value.tag2;
                reducedObject.sum1 += value.sum1;
                reducedObject.sum2 += value.sum2;
                reducedObject.sumQ1 += value.sumQ1;
                reducedObject.sumQ2 += value.sumQ2;
                reducedObject.sumProd += value.sumProd;
                reducedObject.count += value.count;
            });
            return reducedObject; 
        };
```

I call te mapReduce command as:

```
db.recommendation.users.mapReduce(f2, r1,{query: {}, "out": "recommendation.tagsMatch"}).
```

But the console give me the following error:

```
2014-10-27T17:01:28.923+0100 map reduce failed:{
    "errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined near 'ntValue = db.recommendation.tagsMatch.fin'  (line 11)",
    "code" : 16722,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

What's wrong?? How can I fixed that??

Comment: You never initialized db ;)

Comment: You can't access the database from within your `map` or `reduce` functions.  See [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce).

Comment: @JohnnyHK and how can I distinguish if is the first time that a document is map or not? I search on the web but I don't find any answer.

Comment: Probably when you come to call the MR from the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the mapReduce incremental: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/